# Responsive footer with Bootstrap Do't show Complete in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create responsive footer this work currently in desktop but in mobile footer create in half of page not all width.

`footer.blade.php` has this code:

```
 <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container ">
        <div class="col-md-12  col-ms-12 col-xs-12  text-center">
          <ul class="social-network social-circle" >
            <li><a href="#" class="icoinstagram infooter" title="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
  </footer>
```

And footer CSS is:

```
.footer{
  background:#434343;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:100% !important;
  clear: both;
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0;
}
```

Picture of footer in mobile:

[image]

Comment: it's hard to give a good answer without a bit more context - can you create a fiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/